# Uninstall_Init / Uninstall_Exit How do i get access to them in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

To get your windows mobile certified one of the requirements is that you implement these functions to get certified. I personally would love to use these functions to clean up the application data folder.

I have been searching the Internet and i was only able to find a sample that was based on c++ / vb( [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/setupdll.aspx?fid=76996&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick) ) and is from 2004. Is there any solution for doing this in pure managed code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this in pur managed code.  The CAB installer app (wceload.exe) calls into entry points in a DLL, and since there is no CLR Hosting in the CF, there's no way for that to happen for a managed DLL.